# Visual Basic, Check if a sheet exists in another workbook

Tags: vba, excel, file-io

I'm really new to Visual Basic and I don't know any python either, I'm trying to write code that is able to check if a worksheet exists in a workbook...

```
Sub sheetexist()
    If Len(Dir(("C:\My Data\Performance Spreadsheets\[ABCD - Performance.xls]Jun 14"))) Then
        MsgBox "Sheet exist"
    Else
        MsgBox "Sheet does not exist"
    End If
End Sub
```

ABCD does have the sheet for Jun 14 however the code only returns "Sheet does not exist", is there another way to check for worksheets in other workbooks?

Comment: I think you're mis-using the `Dir` function here. That can be used to check the validity of a file or folder *path*.  Is the workbook "ABCD - Performanx.xls" already open, or are you trying to find out if the sheet exists in a *closed* workbook?

Comment: You need to open the workbook to check if a sheet exists in that workbook. `Dir()` doesn't handle what you're attempting.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/excel-vba-how-to-test-if-sheet-exists/6688482#6688482

Comment: Is there a way to check if a sheet exists in closed workbooks? That is what I'm trying to accomplish...

Comment: Yes, see code in my updated answer below. It's possible to use the `ExecuteExcel4Macro` method to query a closed workbook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're mis-using the `Dir` function.

The easiest way to check if a sheet exists is with error-handling.

```
Function SheetExists(wbPath as String, shName as String)
    Dim wb as Workbook
    Dim val

    'Assumes the workbook is NOT open
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbPath)
    On Error Resume Next
    val = wb.Worksheets(shName).Range("A1").Value
    SheetExists = (Err = 0)

    'Close the workbook
    wb.Close

End Function
```

Call the function like this from a worksheet cell:

```
=SheetExists("C:\My Data\Performance Spreadsheets\ABCD - Performance.xls", "Jun 14")
```

Or from VBA like:

```
Debug.Print SheetExists("C:\My Data\Performance Spreadsheets\ABCD - Performance.xls", "Jun 14")
```

Without opening the workbook, you could use the code [here](http://www.exceltip.com/files-workbook-and-worksheets-in-vba/read-information-from-a-closed-workbook-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html).

This will raise an error if any part of the formula can't evaluate (e.g., if you pass the name of a non-existent sheet, a bad file path, etc., `Error 2023`:

```
Private Function GetInfoFromClosedFile(ByVal wbPath As String, _
    wbName As String, wsName As String, cellRef As String) As Variant
Dim arg As String
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ""
    If Right(wbPath, 1) <> "\" Then wbPath = wbPath & "\"
    If Dir(wbPath & "\" & wbName) = "" Then Exit Function
    arg = "'" & wbPath & "[" & wbName & "]" & _
        wsName & "'!" & Range(cellRef).Address(True, True, xlR1C1)
    On Error Resume Next
    GetInfoFromClosedFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
End Function
```

Call it:

```
Sub Test()
Dim path As String
Dim filename As String
Dim sheetName As String
Dim cellAddress As String

path = "c:\users\you\desktop"

filename = "file.xlsx"

sheetName = "Jun 14"

cellAddress = "A1"

Dim v As Variant  'MUST BE VARIANT SO IT CAN CONTAIN AN ERROR VALUE

v = GetInfoFromClosedFile(path, filename, sheetName, cellAddress)
If IsError(v) Then MsgBox "Sheet or filename doesn't exist!"


End Sub
```