# VBA Evaluation error 2023 not thrown

Tags: vba, excel

Withing my macro I am trying to check, if another workbook contains specific sheet without opening the workbook.

I was following these two articles:

- [Visual Basic, Check if a sheet exists in another workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916234/visual-basic-check-if-a-sheet-exists-in-another-workbook)
- [Read information from a closed workbook using VBA in Microsoft Excel
  2010](http://www.exceltip.com/files-workbook-and-worksheets-in-vba/read-information-from-a-closed-workbook-using-vba-in-microsoft-excel.html)

The thing is, that the part ExecuteExcel4Macro (arg) should throw (in my case) Error 2023 (General evaluation error) 
I was trying to test it out, if it works properly. I was faking sheet names that are not present within this workbook.

Example:
DataWorkbook contains 2 sheets: InputData and Notes
MacroWorkbook contains this following macro

```
Private Function checkSheet(ByVal path As String, _
                            ByVal fileName As String, _
                            ByVal sheetName As Strgin) As Boolean
  Dim arg = "'" & path & "[" & fileName & "]" & _
            sheetName & "'!" & Range("A1").Address(True, True, xlR1C1)

  ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)

  If Err = 0
    checkSheets = True
  Else 
    Err.Raise 1
  End If
End Function
```

I call the function with fake sheetname (let's say DataFake as sheetName).
Then when I break the execution before *ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)* and within immediate window I call *ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)* it gives me Error 2023 (that's right because there is no such sheet called DataFake) but I run macro again (I assume Error 2023 was raised) my second part of function should raise new Error with Number 1 (this error is handeled afterwards). Problem is, that it does not end up in Else part. For some reason Err = 0 (I also tried Err.Number = 0) both with same result. It says there is no error even if it should shout there is an error.

Any ideas?

Comment: After a macro throws an error it goes into Error handling mode so it would stop and never reach your if/else statement. See [error handling](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm) on how to do this properly.

Comment: you need to restart the file (or stop debugging), and add a line including `on error resume next` before the error line (being here `ExecuteEcel4Macro` line)