# Check if sheet exists

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if the sheet named "test" exists and if not, create and name that sheet to "test".

If it exists, I run a separate block of code which I haven't put up here. I have used error handling in that it ignores the error if it happens.

```
If Sheets("test").Name = "" Then  
'MsgBox Sheets("test").Name & "Name"  
.Worksheets.Add         After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test2")  
.ActiveSheet.Name = "test"  
End If
```

No matter what I do, this section of the code always runs and creates a new sheet.

The code runs properly if the sheet "test" doesn't exist already. It creates a new sheet and renames it and moves on. Obviously it doesn't rename the sheet in the other case since there's already another sheet "test" with the same name.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test or check if sheet exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure why you're getting additional worksheets added, but I would use and external function to check whether the worksheet exists...

I would also add some error checking for "test2" so here is some code which you should be able to adapt

```
Sub Test()
    Dim wsName As String: wsName = "test"
    If Not WorkSheetExists(wsName) Then Worksheets.Add().Name = wsName
    If WorkSheetExists("test2") Then Worksheets(wsName).Move _
        After:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test2")
End Sub

Function WorkSheetExists(ByVal strName As String) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   WorkSheetExists = Not ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(strName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

*** EDIT ***

> Updated function to specify which workbook should be tested

```
Function WorkSheetExists(ByVal SheetName As String, Optional ByRef WorkbookToTest As Workbook) As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   If WorkbookToTest Is Nothing Then Set WorkbookToTest = ThisWorkbook
   WorkSheetExists = Not WorkbookToTest.Worksheets(SheetName) Is Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: does not work. Tried this method and also the for (loop through all worksheets), basically they do nothing. it doesn't go near the wsname sheet at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not too familiar with VBA, you could use this rather than a function:

```
Sub checkSheet()
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        If Worksheets(i).Name = "MySheet" Then
            exists = True
        End If
    Next i

    If Not exists Then
        Worksheets.Add.Name = "MySheet"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way of achieving this would be to create a dictionary of the sheet names.

You can then use the exists function to test whether the sheet exists or not

```
Dim sheetNames As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

' Create and populate dictionary
Set sheetNames = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    sheetNames.Add ws.Name, ws.Index
Next ws

' Test if sheet exists
If Not sheetNames.Exists("test") Then
    ' If not add to workbook
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(after:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test2")).Name = "test"
    ' add sheet to dictionary
    sheetNames.Add "test", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("test").Index
End If
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
Function IsExists(name As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sheet As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(name)
     On Error GoTo 0
     IsExists = Not sheet Is Nothing
 End Function
```

Comment: Just in case the OP has a limited knowledge of vba, how would you combine what you just posted with what the OP is trying to do with his/her code?

Comment: I give this as a plus one - you pass the name of the sheet and workbook reference rather than look at each sheet in turn.  @Scott It will return TRUE/FALSE - so `IF NOT IsExists("Sheet1") THEN`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook, I know how to use it, but for a good answer it needs to show the OP how to reference the Function from the sub.