# How to add a worksheet with the value of the cell I double clicked

Tags: vba, excel

I developed this code to select a worksheet named with the text of a cell on column B when I double click on it.
But I am trying to increase my code with one IF condition:
 If there is no worksheet named with the cell I double clicked show a msgbox ("Hello")
and after that create the worksheet with the name of the cell I double clicked.

```
Option Explicit


Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

If Target.Column = 2 Then

If Sheets(Target.Text) = True Then
Sheets(Target.Text).Visible = xlSheetVisible
Sheets(Target.Text).Select
Sheets(Target.Text).Range("A2").Select

Cancel = True
Else
MsgBox ("hello")

End If
End If

End Sub
```

This condition does not work as I thought
    If Sheets(Target.Text) = True Then

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test or check if sheet exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sheets(Target.Text)` is a `Worksheet`-object, you cannot compare it to a boolean. Furthermore, if the sheet doesn't exists, you will get a runtime error. What you want is a function to check if a worksheet exists. You can find many examples, for example [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)

Copy such a function into your code and change your event handler

```
If SheetExists(Target.Text) Then
    Sheets(Target.Text).Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheets(Target.Text).Select
    Sheets(Target.Text).Range("A2").Select
    Cancel = True
Else
    MsgBox ("hello")
End If
```