# Error Handling when sheet does not exist

Tags: excel, vba

```
If Error(Sheets(ws_str)) = True Then Exit Sub
```

Returns run-time error 9.
I know this sheet does not exist. How do I do errorhandling in cases where the worksheet does not exist?

Comment: You can use the answers given to create an **UDF** (User Defined Function) and have the worksheet as input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test or check if sheet exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the little piece of code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SheetExits()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws_str As String

ws_str = "aaa" ' for test

On Error Resume Next
Set ws = Worksheets(ws_str)
On Error GoTo 0
If ws Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem:

```
Sub ErrorHandling()
On Error GoTo ExitSub
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("NonExistingSheet") 'it will throw an error
MsgBox ("This won't be displayed")

ExitSub:
End Sub
```

Basically, at the beginning define, where your code should resume in case of an error. To satisfy your requirement, place the resuming point right before `End Sub`, so it goes directly there in case of an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Function SheetExists(sheetname as string) as boolean
 On error goto whoops
 dim ws as worksheet
 set ws = worksheets(sheetname)
 set ws = nothing
 sheetexists = true
 exit function
 whoops:
 sheetexists = false
 end function
```