# Macro to copy sheets from different files into single one

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have a workbook for each person in my team where they have a worksheet named `"Panel"` that contains their initiatives and progress.
I want to develop a unified spreadsheet containing all their initiatives to have a view of the whole area.

In each `"Panel"` sheet, the `"U5"` cell contains the name of the owner. In my consolidated file, I want to put the name of the owner as the name of the corresponding sheet.

I made this macro to get, from a separate folder where they will all put their individual sheets, all the `"Panel"` sheets, put them in the main file and rename them to identify the owner.

Later on, I'll develop a database with the initiatives, identifying the start and end of the data fields to compile them in a single manner for a dashboard.

This is my code:

```
Sub GetSheets()
    Path = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PMO\Test consolidation\Independent files"
    Filename = Dir(Path & "*.xlsm")

    Dim wsname As String

    Do While Filename <> ""
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True

        Worksheets("Panel").Activate
        Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Worksheets("Panel").Select
        wsname = Range("U5")
        Worksheets("Panel").Name = wsname

        Workbooks(Filename).Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Can you help to identify why this is not working?
Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you are missing a backslash between your path and wildcard.

Comment: There are a few things to look at: **1.** Try and qualify your workbooks and/or worksheets. **2.** You don't have to **`Activate`** or **`Select`** your worksheets once you have qualified them. **3.** When you say **`this is not working`**, what do you mean? Is it not copying the sheets over? are you not getting the values from `U5`? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example which checks whether path has `\` present, whether sheets exists (code a la Rory) and also whether U5 is empty. Assumes, U5 in workbooks you are opening are being used for renaming.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSheets()
    Dim path As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim wbMaster As Workbook
    Dim wbActive As Workbook
    Dim wsPanel As Worksheet

    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook

    path = "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\PMO\Test consolidation\Independent files"
    If Right$(path, 1) <> "\" Then path = path & "\"
    Filename = Dir(path & "*.xlsm")

    Dim wsname As String

    Do While Filename <> ""     
        Set wbActive = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & Filename, ReadOnly:=True)

        With wbActive
            If Evaluate("ISREF('" & "Panel" & "'!A1)") Then 'Rory 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists
                Set wsPanel = wbActive.Worksheets("Panel")
                wsPanel.Copy After:=wbMaster.Worksheets(1)

                If Not IsEmpty(wsPanel.Range("U5")) Then
                    ActiveSheet.Name = wsPanel.Range("U5")
                Else
                    MsgBox "Missing value to rename worksheet in " & Filename
                End If
            End If
        End With

        wbActive.Close
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Adding the backslash should happen directly after `path = …` otherwise `Dir(path & "*.xlsm")` will still fail! So you should swap the lines.

Comment: Sorry. Typo. I was pasting into mobile and trying to delete /re-arrange some lines.

Comment: Amazing, works like a charm! Many thanks for the help!

Comment: Just another quick question: in case I want to paste the sheets as values, why isn't this working?

    ...
    wsPanel.Copy After:=wbMaster.Worksheets(1)
    With wbMaster.Sheets(2)
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and then comparing the syntax?  It is a little difficult from code in a comment to work out what is on new lines.

Comment: it may be that after moving you need to select all cells and then convert to values