# Existence of shapes in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint, shapes

I would like to build a condition on a command button on a Macro enabled powerpoint presentation. If the shape exists then I would like it deleted, otherwise the button should produce a statement about the fact that there is no such shape. Currently I am having trouble with existence...! How do I get Power point to recognise the shape is null? Here is my code:

```
If ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("Picture") Is Nothing Then
  MsgBox "no Picture"
Else
  ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes("Picture").Delete
  MsgBox "Picture Cleared"
End If
```

This code only produces an error because the shape doesn't exist so the first if statement fails. Perhaps we need to check whether its in the selection pane?

Comment: Perhaps you do not have a shape on slide 3 with the name "Picture"? What do you see if you run the following in the Immediate window? `For Each sh in ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Shapes: debug.print sh.Name: Next`

Comment: Indeed, if the shape is not there, then I want a message box saying as such. ie "shape "Pictures" not there". If it is there, I want it deleted

Comment: You can loop through each shape on the slide and check if the name "Pictures" exists. Or you can catch the error as indicated in this question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6688482/1445609)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @davidmneedham gives in the link in the comments (@[TimWilliams answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists/6688482#6688482)), you can use a construct similar to as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim shp As Shape
Dim myshapeName As String
myshapeName = "Picture"
Dim sl As Slide

Set sl = ActivePresentation.Slides(1)

 If shapePresent(sl, myshapeName) Then

     sl.Shapes(myshapeName).Delete

 Else

    MsgBox myshapeName & " not present"

 End If

End Sub


Private Function shapePresent(ByVal sl As Slide, ByVal myshapeName As String) As Boolean

   On Error GoTo errhand

   sl.Shapes(myshapeName).Select

   shapePresent = True
   Exit Function

errhand:

shapePresent = False
Err.Clear

End Function
```

Using the same format as that answer:

```
Private Function shapePresent(ByVal sl As Slide, ByVal myshapeName As String) As Boolean

    Dim myShape As Shape

    On Error Resume Next

    Set myShape = sl.Shapes(myshapeName)

    On Error GoTo 0

    shapePresent = Not myShape Is Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

Some of the other suggestions will work but in general, it's bad practice to rely on selection unless absolutely necessary.  Instead, you could call a slightly different function:

```
Function ShapeExists(ByVal oSl as Slide, ByVal ShapeName as String) as Boolean
   Dim oSh as Shape
   For Each oSh in oSl.Shapes
     If oSh.Name = ShapeName Then
        ShapeExists = True
        Exit Function
     End If
   Next ' Shape
   ' No shape here, so though it's not strictly necessary:
   ShapeExists = False
End Function
```

You could also modify this to return a reference to the shape if found or nothing if not.

If you prefer not to use early Exit Functions, there are easy ways to write around that.

Comment: Upvoted. I felt a bit guilty about the .Select being in there!