# VBA: runtime error '424' Object required when searching for Shape

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, shapes

I created a VBA script to transfer data from Excel to PowerPoint (both Version 2016) and want to check if there exists a specific Shape on Slide x and then copy it to Slide y.

The common solution which is also mentioned in ([Existence of shapes in Powerpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343425/existence-of-shapes-in-powerpoint)) does produce

> "runtime error '424': Object required"

in line 3 of the function at `For Each oSh in myPresentation.Slides(4).Shape`

```
Function ShapeExists(ByVal ShapeName as String) as Boolean

Dim oSh as Shape

For Each oSh in myPresentation.Slides(4).Shapes
     If oSh.Name = ShapeName Then
        ShapeExists = True
        Exit Function
     End If
Next
End Function
```

The code where "ShapeExists" is called:

```
Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

 If ShapeExists("MSDreieck2") Then
    myPresentation.Slides(4).Shapes("MSDreieck2").Copy
    mySlide5.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=0
 Else
    GoTo NACHZEITSTRAHLCOPY:
 End If
```

I already added the Object Library for Powerpoint 2016 under references and several others. 
When typing `dim oSh as Shape` it suggests two different "Shape" items in the list (one for Excel, one for PP) but it doesn't make a difference for the error which one I use.

As far as I'm concerned there is no other way to check if a specific Shape exists as the Shape index gets newly assigned at every run and as the number of Shapes on Slide x is not always the same in my case.

I would be very grateful for every suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: `myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add` BTW if you are adding a presentation then how come you are trying to get the 4th slide?

Comment: I am working with VBA for only a week now. I got this from the internet and it has been working fine for me. It does not create a new presentation everytime I use ```myPresentation```

Comment: What the above code does is create a powerpoint object and then adds a new presentation to it. Right after that you are checking if there is a shape in slide 4? A new presentation will not have slide 4.

Comment: ok, how should I write it then? ```PowerPointApp.Presentations(?).Slides(4).Shapes```?

Comment: You need to open the relevant powerpoint file. `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Open(FileName)` Where  **FileName** is the name and path of the powerpoint file

Comment: the file has not been saved at this point in time, but it is called "Presentation1". I tried it and got the same error

Comment: If it is not saved then you need to work with the open file and not add a new one using `.Add`

Comment: I also tried it with ```ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Shapes``` and got runtime error '-2147221164 (80040154)': class not registered

Comment: Refresh the page. I have updated the answer. See if that helps?

Comment: I opened the presentation and started the code you posted. Error: ```Item Presentation1 not found in the Presentations collection```
The presentation is definitely called "Presentation1". I can see it at the top of the window

Comment: I just tested my code and it works. Are you sure there is an open presentaiton called `Presentation1`

Comment: yes I am sure - I edited my comment above

Comment: Did you make any changes to my code. I just opened a new presentation and ran my code and it works just fine.

Comment: What happens if you type `msgbox PowerPointApp.Presentations.count` before `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations("Presentation1")` What do you get?

Comment: At what level of the code is `myPresentation` being `Dim`ed?  Is this object Local to the calling procedure (so `ShapeExists` can't see it), or at the Module level? (Assuming that you *are* using Explicit Variable Declaration.  If not, shove `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, and have a look into why that can be so important...)

Comment: @SiddharthRout the msgbox returns "1"

Comment: Great. now replace `msgbox PowerPointApp.Presentations.count` with `msgbox PowerPointApp.Presentations(1).name`. What do you get?

Comment: @SiddharthRout it returns "Presentation1"

Comment: @SiddharthRout I am getting "runtime error 91 object variable or with block variable not set" now

Comment: On which line??

Comment: sorry, I managed to create a workaround for this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is available in both Excel and Powerpoint, avoid confusing the code by explicitly declaring it :)

```
Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape
```

or

```
Dim oSh As Object
```

If you do not explicitly declare it, it will refer to the Object from the Native Application which is Excel in this case. `Object` does late binding and leaves the Application to decide at runtime.

**EDIT**

A basic example on how to achieve what you want using LATE BINDING (**The below code is Untested**). Let me know if you get any errors.

```
Option Explicit

Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim oPPSlide As Object

Sub Sample()       
    '~~> Establish an PowerPoint application object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No Powerpoint Instance found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    PowerPointApp.Visible = True
    
    '~~> Work with open Presentation1
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations("Presentation1")
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant slide which has the shape
    Set oPPSlide = myPresentation.Slides(4)
    
    If ShapeExists("MSDreieck2") Then
        '
        '~~> Rest of your code
        '
    End If
End Sub


Function ShapeExists(ByVal ShapeName As String) As Boolean
    Dim oSh As Object
    
    For Each oSh In oPPSlide.Shapes
      If oSh.Name = ShapeName Then
         ShapeExists = True
         Exit Function
      End If
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: both of these are producing the exact same error message

Comment: is `myPresentation` declared and initialized? I do not see that in the function?

Comment: yes, I declared ```Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add``` and ```Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")```

Comment: Can you please update the quesiton with the exact code so that I can try it at my end?

Comment: I updated the question and copied the part where the function is called. Unfortunately I cannot post the whole sub as it is 2k lines long and contains work-related data.

Comment: Where have you declared `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add`. I am more interested in this part of the code

Comment: I declared it at the beginning of the sub. Later on in this sub, the ShapeExist function is called as shown above

Comment: thank you very much for your help. The code you posted in your EDIT is exactly the same as mine except for the filepath as it is not saved at this point

Comment: You are looking at the old code. Refresh the page :)

Comment: @clemens `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add` is not Declaring it.  Declaring it is the `Dim myPresentation As Object` bit in Siddharth Rout's code.  (i.e. tell VBA that `myPresentation` *exists*, before you start trying to *use* it)

Comment: @Chronocidal I have ```Dim myPresentation As Object``` at the beginning of my sub

Comment: @clemens If it is *inside* the `Sub` (i.e. after the `Sub WhateverItsCalled()` line), then the `ShapeExists` function can't see it - a bit like hanging up a poster inside your house versus outside your house, and expecting neighbours to notice.