# Selecting Range with variables, Run time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

VBA keeps giving run time error'1004': Application defined or object defined error  for the code snippet below;

```
Sub deneme()

    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Integer

    For a = 12 To 13

        For b = 2 To 3

            Sheets(2).Select

            ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 1).Select

            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

            ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 1).Value & " " & Left(Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 2).Value, 18)

            ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D1").Select

            Selection.Merge

            ActiveCell.Select

            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 1).Value

            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With

            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select

            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 2)).Select

            Selection.Merge

            ActiveCell.Select

            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Worksheets(2).Cells(8, b + 1)

            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With

            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(b, 3), Cells(b, 4)).Select

            Selection.Merge

            ActiveCell.Select

            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Worksheets(2).Cells(a, b + 1).Value

            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With

        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

Two different variables a and b is working normally when seperated, however when i wrote them down together vba gives 1004 error.

I use the code for taking different values and arranging them in a new worksheet. This is only a small part of it which was working normally before.

Answer (score 0):

This line is the problem:

```
 ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 1).Value & " " & Left(Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 2).Value, 18)
```

You have it inside:

```
For b = 2 To 3

 Next b
```

As you don't account for the second loop of b you are trying to create a sheet with the same name and hence the error. You need to find a way to account for the fact you are doing two loops with b instead of the outer loop for a - which you do account for.

I think you probably want to move everything that doesn't involve b, including the sheet add and name, to before the b loop.

Something like, though hard without seeing your data:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub deneme()

    Dim a As Long
    Dim b As Integer

    For a = 12 To 13

        Sheets(2).Select

        ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 1).Select

        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

        ActiveSheet.Name = Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 1).Value & " " & Left(Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 2).Value, 18)

        ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D1").Select

        Selection.Merge

        ActiveCell.Select

        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Worksheets(2).Cells(a, 1).Value

        With Selection
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        End With

        For b = 2 To 3

            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Select

            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(b, 1), Cells(b, 2)).Select

            Selection.Merge

            ActiveCell.Select

            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Worksheets(2).Cells(8, b + 1)

            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With

            ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(b, 3), Cells(b, 4)).Select

            Selection.Merge

            ActiveCell.Select

            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = Worksheets(2).Cells(a, b + 1).Value

            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With

        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

**Primarily:** You should include a test for the [existence of a sheet name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists) before trying to name a sheet. What happens if different rows in column A lead to you trying to create a sheet with the same name?

After that, you should start looking at using worksheet variables, avoiding `.Select`,  using `With` statements and `Option Explicit`, looking at ways `.FormulaR1C1`can be applied to an entire range rather than in a loop to the current ActiveCell and pulling out repeated lines of code into functions. Could also used typed function `Left$` rather than `Left`.

The code I posted also depends on what you actually wanted to happen if the same sheet name came up.. did you want to create a new name or did you want to use the existing sheet. All stuff error handling on sheet and a test for sheet exists could deal with.

Comment: Thank you sir for the fast reply and sory for my late one.

Comment: I couldn't return to your answer due to my work schedule. Actually I figured out the problem.   Firstly i made sure that there won't be any duplicate sheet names with some cross checks.  However my error is very fundamental. I forgot to write my code to a module or a form. I directly try to work from the sheet. Because of that whenewer other sheet is activated code stops working.  This also linked to the problem you adressed about my code writing. I learned to code by myself and still my writing is bulky. I am trying to improve it. Again thanks for your help...

Comment: It’s a pleasure :-)