# Check if worksheet exists by name

Tags: vba, excel

I am wanting to validate if a worksheet exists, and if not then ask the user to enter select a sheet from those that exist.  Looking over the information on [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)  i came up with a function that returns a boolean and then I will prompt if the result is false.

I am having an issue where the custom sheet names I have entered return false, but the default "Sheet1"... return true.  Looking over the object model I do not see one listed for Worksheets.Name.Value and looking at the project explorer I see that the sheets are listed as `Sheet 1 (Macro Variables).

How do I reference the name of the sheet in parenthesis so that my function will work, or if not possible using sheet names, is there a better solution?

Here is my code

```
    Sub TestBed()
    Dim wb As Workbook, test As Boolean, debugStr As String, wsNames() As String
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Debug.Print "List of sheets in this workbook"

    For i = 1 To wb.Worksheets.count
        ReDim Preserve wsNames(i - 1)
        wsNames(i - 1) = wb.Worksheets(i).Name
        debugStr = debugStr & wsNames(i - 1) & " | "
    Next i

    Debug.Print debugStr
    debugStr = ""

    For i = LBound(wsNames) To UBound(wsNames)
        test = ValidateWorksheetExists(wsNames(i), wb)
        debugStr = debugStr & wsNames(i) & " = " & test & " | "
    Next i

    Debug.Print debugStr
End Sub

Function ValidateWorksheetExists(sName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean

If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    With wb
        For i = 1 To .Worksheets.count
            If wb.Worksheets(i).Name = sName Then
                ValidateWorksheetExists = True
            Else
                ValidateWorksheetExists = False
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I'm confused, the bit in brackets is the sheet name. The bit in front is the Code Name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although a Boolean variable (err function in this case) defaults to **False** when declared, it's good practice to be explicit... and since **ValidateWorksheetExists** starts out as **False**, there's no need to again set it to **False**. Doing so reverts a possible **True** state that was set on a prior iteration of '**i**'

```
Function ValidateWorksheetExists(sName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean

If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook

ValidateWorksheetExists = False

    With wb
        For i = 1 To .Worksheets.count
            If wb.Worksheets(i).Name = sName Then
                ValidateWorksheetExists = True
            End If
        Next i
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the point of the default value of being set to false.  I was overwriting true values to false.  I was under the assumption that once I provided a return value for the function that the function would stop processing iterations and exit. Both a logical and lack of understanding of how VBA processes escapes from functions on my part

Answer (score 2):

You need to exit the function right after:

```
ValidateWorksheetExists = True
```

Otherwise the next iteration of `i` will set it to `False` again.

*(there may be other errors)*