# Activate sheet 1 otherwise another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I tried to modify the following two lines of code by adding an if statement, but it didn't work. Does anyone know why?

```
Workbooks(wkbk_Record).Activate
Workbooks(wkbk_Record).Sheets("Tab1").Select
```

What's wrong with the following? Thank you

```
If SheetExists("Tab1", Workbooks(wkbk_Record)) Then    
    Workbooks(wkbk_Record).Activate
    Workbooks(wkbk_Record).Sheets("Tab1").Select    
Else    
    Workbooks(wkbk_Record).Activate
    Workbooks(wkbk_Record).Sheets("Tab2").Select
```

Comment: Do you have code for `SheetExists`?

Comment: It can't be `End if` right?

Comment: yes, "If SheetExists("Tab1", Workbooks(wkbk_Record))" is being used about 20 lines before.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that you take the `SheetExists` from here - [Test or check if sheet exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists) this is something that works:

```
Sub TestMe()

    If SheetExists("Tab1") Then
        Sheets("Tab1").Select
    ElseIf SheetExists("Tab2") Then
        Sheets("Tab2").Select
    Else
        MsgBox "No Sheet"
    End If

End Sub

 Function SheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean

     Dim sht As Worksheet

     If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     On Error Resume Next
     Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
     On Error GoTo 0
     SheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing

 End Function
```

Or if you wanna see your colleagues get crazy, write it like this:

```
Sub ActivateTab2OrTab1()

    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Tab2").Select
    Sheets("Tab1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: OP - This is a good opportunity to learn how to set a Worksheet variable, instead of `Select`ing the worksheet.  See [how to avoid `.Select`/`.Activate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So I can use "Sub" under another "Sub" that already exists? Thanks !

Comment: @BurtBee, yes, *If* you have ended the previous `Sub`routine with `End Sub`

Comment: (oh ok, this is embedded in a really long sub, so I probably can't use it on its own with another sub)

Comment: Or could you explain why my codes don't work? I thought I was just modifying it little bit. Thanks !

Comment: @BurtBee - no idea what does not work. Just from the first look - you are missing `Sub Something` , `End Sub` and `End If`.

Comment: @BurtBee - you are welcome. If my asnwer has solved your query, you may consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)