# Using error handling to delete sheets based on listbox value

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

So I have a listbox with a number of names and one value which is an "all names" option. When a name is selected, a worksheet is added with information about this name. When "all names" are selected, multiple worksheets are added, one for each name.

I am trying to put in some error handling that will delete the existing name sheet if someone selects the same one twice. I was able to get the code working for the "all names" function, to where it will delete all sheets except the dashboards/background data and then re-insert the name sheets. However, I am having trouble getting it to work where one single name is selected.

Here is my error handling code. I have it go to this OnError. For the second part, I am just using one of the potential name values, John. The sheet name and listbox value would be the same.

```
ErrorHandling:

If (Err.Number = 1004 And EmpListBox.Value = "All Names")Then
   For Each ws In Worksheets
     Select Case ws.Name
     Case "Dashboard", "Data", "Employees"
     Case Else
         ws.Delete
     End Select
   Next
'this is where it is not working
ElseIf (Err.Number = 1004 And EmpListBox.Value = "John") Then
    Sheets("John").Delete
Resume Main
End If
```

Comment: Use a function that returns a boolean if sheet exists and call that https://stackoverflow.com/q/6688131/6241235 you can then probably re-write the above and remove the current error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ErrorHandling:

```
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    If EmpListBox.Value = "All Names" Then
        For Each ws In Worksheets
            Select Case ws.Name
                Case "Dashboard", "Data", "Employees"
                Case Else
                    ws.Delete
            End Select
       Next
   Else
       Sheets(EmpListBox.Value).Delete
   End If
End If
Resume Main
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked perfectly! Still threw in a sheet1, etc. but with a left function could easily delete those extra sheets.