# How do i select a sheet by using a date variable?

Tags: excel, vba, date, variables

I've been trying to select and delete a sheet by using this variable szTodayDate but i keep getting the run-time error 9.

```
Option Explicit
Dim szTodayDate As String

Public Sub AddSheetsTodayDate()

    szTodayDate = Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yy")

    On Error GoTo MakeSheet
    Sheets(szTodayDate).Activate
    Exit Sub
MakeSheet:
    Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = szTodayDate

End Sub

Public Sub RecordProgress()
    Worksheets(szTodayDate).Select  
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line are you having the error?

Comment: Worksheets(szTodayDate).Select 

Sry i didn't specify earlier

Comment: On debug, what is the value of szTodayDate and what's the Sheet's name?

Comment: It shows a blank value. Just "". The sheet's supposed to be named the current date in the "dd-mm-yy" format. The first sub procedure works and creates a sheet of that name. But when i try to select the worksheet using the variable i've defined  "worksheets(sztodaydate).select" runs into an error

Comment: Did the answer below work for you?

Comment: Perhaps, there's no a sheet with such name. Are you confident that `szTodayDate` holds correct name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with your declaration of `szTodayDate`. Change it to:
`Public szTodayDate As String`

Comment: That worked! Strange, I thought declaring variables as public under option explicit made them module level variables and I was working within a module.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you:

I have used `Evaluate` as mentioned by Rory in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28473714/5720144) to check if the sheet Exists.

```
Option Explicit
Public szTodayDate As String

Public Sub AddSheetsTodayDate()

    Dim WorksheetExists As Boolean
    Dim ws As Worksheet

        szTodayDate = format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy")
        WorksheetExists = Evaluate("ISREF('" & szTodayDate & "'!A1)")

    If Not WorksheetExists Then

        Sheets.Add , Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = szTodayDate

    Else: Sheets(szTodayDate).Activate

    End If

End Sub

Public Sub RecordProgress()
    Worksheets(szTodayDate).Select  
End Sub
```