# how to pull records from access to excel WEEKLY using ADO

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ado

I am trying to create a macro that will export new records from access to an Excel file each week. Currently my code has it adding a new sheet to the Excel file, but how can I get it to just update a sheet that's already in the file?

```
Const ConStrAccess As String = "xxxx;"

Sub CopyDataFomDatabase()

    Dim BrokerConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim BrokerData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim BrokerField As ADODB.Field

    Set BrokerConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set BrokerData = New ADODB.Recordset

    BrokerConn.ConnectionString = ConStrAccess
    BrokerConn.Open

    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    With BrokerData
        .ActiveConnection = BrokerConn
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM xxxxx;"
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    On Error GoTo CloseRecordset

    Worksheets.Add

    For Each BrokerField In BrokerData.Fields
        ActiveCell.Value = BrokerField.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next BrokerField

    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset BrokerData
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

CloseRecordset:
    BrokerData.Close

CloseConnection:
    BrokerConn.Close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the name of the worksheet, you can simply specify the name in the code below instead of `Sheet1`. It will create it if it does not exist. If you leave it empty, this will select the active worksheet in the workbook that this code runs on.

Note: I made the assumption that this will be run on the workbook where you save the result. If this is not the case, replacing `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` is necessary.

```
Const ConStrAccess As String = "xxxx;"

Const sheetName As String = "Sheet1"

Sub CopyDataFomDatabase()

    Dim BrokerConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim BrokerData As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim BrokerField As ADODB.Field

    Set BrokerConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set BrokerData = New ADODB.Recordset

    BrokerConn.ConnectionString = ConStrAccess
    BrokerConn.Open

    On Error GoTo CloseConnection

    With BrokerData
        .ActiveConnection = BrokerConn
        .Source = "SELECT * FROM xxxxx;"
        .LockType = adLockReadOnly
        .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
        .Open
    End With

    On Error GoTo CloseRecordset

    Dim selectedWorksheet As Worksheet

    'If no name is given it will select the active one
    If sheetName = vbNullString Then
        Set selectedWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

    'If the sheet with this name does not exist, it will be created and activated
    'For checking if it exists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44130825/
    ElseIf WorksheetFunction.IsErr(Evaluate("'" & sheetName & "'!A1"))    Then        
        Set selectedWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add()
        selectedWorksheet.Name = sheetName
        selectedWorksheet.Activate

    'Simply actives the sheet   
    Else
        Set selectedWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sheetName)
        selectedWorksheet.Activate

    End If

    For Each BrokerField In BrokerData.Fields
        ActiveCell.Value = BrokerField.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Next BrokerField

    Range("A1").Select
    Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset BrokerData
    Range("A1").CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

CloseRecordset:
    BrokerData.Close

CloseConnection:
    BrokerConn.Close
```