# Is there a possibility to put an OR while referencing a sheet name?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm calling multiple workbooks and they all contain a sheet named either Desk or Desk_ or _Desk.
I need to use data in these sheets to build pivots et cetera.

I am unable to use
Sheets("Desk" or "Desk_" or "_Desk").Activate 
to reach these sheets.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: There are functions to check if a sheet exists (search on this site for them) and then `If Sheet Then Sheets("Desk").Activate` although, id avoid relying on the active sheet

Answer (score 0):

Use this function (which you can also pass a workbook variable to) to determine if a sheet exists (sourced from [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)):

```
Function WorksheetExists(shtName As String, Optional wb As Workbook) As Boolean
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    Set sht = wb.Sheets(shtName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    WorksheetExists = Not sht Is Nothing
End Function
```

---

You can call this function from your macro to dynamically assign your sheet. A few things to note here:

1. If more than one of your target sheets exist, the code will assign your sheet variable to the first one that hits a match
2. You may want to account for the possibility that none of the sheets exist

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet

'Dynamically assign worksheet variable
If WorksheetExists("Sheet1") Then
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
ElseIf WorksheetExists("Sheet2") Then
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet2")
ElseIf WorksheetExists("Sheet3") Then
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet3")
End If

'Account for none of the sheets existing
If ws Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "None of sheets exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

MsgBox ws.Name

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use formulas

> to activate Sheet1 from workbook Food
> `=HYPERLINK("[food.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2","goto Food.Sheet1")`
>
> Get value of A2 if workbook Food is opened
> `=[food.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$2`
>
> If not opened use its path
> `='C:\[food.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$2`