# Copy and rename a worksheet when opening excel file

Tags: excel

Hi I am trying to copy a worksheet every month from a master using a macro in VB i have managed to copy and rename the new worksheet but get an error when i close and reopen the file because the name exists i am new to VB :) Code i have is

---

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Master").Visible = True
Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
NewPageName = Format(Date, "MMYY")
ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Name = NewPageName
End Sub
```

---

Comment: `NewPageName = Format(Date, "MMYY")` IF you execute this more than once per day, then the worksheet will already exist after 1st run. Think a different way of naming the sheet, or delete it before copying it. A Workbook cannot contain 2 worksheets with same name

Comment: I want this to copy Every month and rename to the new month

Comment: Check first if the monthly worksheet exists and if not create it as you have done.  For checking existence of a sheet see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Sheets("Master").Visible = True
Sheets("Master").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
NewPageName = Format(Date, "mmmm")
ActiveWindow.ActiveSheet.Name = NewPageName

End Sub

Comment: Changed a bit to make the name the month but i still cant stop the error if i am in that month

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you edit your question to include the error text? It would help others to find the question, answer it or solve their own problem.