# Extracting a range of non-contiguous cells

Tags: excel, vba

Extracting a range of non-contiguous cells within number of excel files in a particular folder (data has to be pulled from either of 2 UNIQUE SHEETS)

I have the below code for pulling data (range of cells) that are non-contiguous and pasting them in a new sheet. However, the code needs to look for the data in either of the 2 sheets , namely -  "summary1" or "extract1".

[Note- Only one of the two sheets would be available in each file]
I can successfully pull for one of them but if i add both of them using "On Error Resume Next" i get an error. Kindly guide me on how to resolve this!

Any suggestions or tips are much appreciate!!

Code:

```
Sub PIdataextraction()

Dim myFile As String, path As String
Dim erow As Long, col As Long

path = "C:\Users\New\"
myFile = Dir(path & "*.xl??")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do While myFile <> ""
Workbooks.Open (path & myFile)
Windows(myFile).Activate

Set copyrange = Sheets("summary1").Range("B4,E7,E9,E11,E13,E15,I12,J22,C24,C25,C26,I11,R16")

On Error Resume Next

Set copyrange = Sheets("extract1").Range("B4,E7,E9,E11,E13,E15,I12,J22,C24,C25,C26,I11,R16")

Windows("MasterFile.xlsm").Activate

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

col = 1
For Each cel In copyrange
cel.Copy

Cells(erow, col).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

col = col + 1

Next

Windows(myFile).Close savechanges:=False
myFile = Dir()
Loop
Range("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Data has been Compiled,Please Check!"

End Sub
```

Comment: I would a function to see if the sheet exists. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach which factors out the "find one of these sheets in a workbook" logic into a separate function.

```vb
Sub PIdataextraction()

    Const PTH As String = "C:\Users\New\" 'use const for fixed values
    Const RNG As String = "B4,E7,E9,E11,E13,E15,I12,J22,C24,C25,C26,I11,R16"
    
    Dim myFile As String, path As String, c As Range
    Dim erow As Long, col As Long, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).row
    myFile = Dir(PTH & "*.xl??")
    
    Do While myFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & myFile)
        
        Set ws = FindFirstSheet(wb, Array("summary1", "extract1"))
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then       'check we got a sheet
            col = 1
            For Each c In ws.Range(RNG).Cells
                Sheet1.Cells(erow, col).Value = c.Value
                col = col + 1
            Next c
            Sheet1.Cells(erow, col).Value = wb.Name '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
            erow = erow + 1
        Else
            Debug.Print "No sheet found in " & ws.Name
        End If
        
        wb.Close savechanges:=False
        myFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Range("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data has been Compiled,Please Check!"

End Sub

'Given a workbook `wb`, return the first sheet found from 
'  an array of sheet names `SheetNames`
Function FindFirstSheet(wb As Workbook, SheetNames) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet, s
    For Each s In SheetNames
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(s)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then Exit For
    Next s
    Set FindFirstSheet = ws
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim! Thank you for the response

Comment: However, we receive a "VBA 1004 Error" while running the above code. This mostly has to do with - "  Set ws = FindFirstSheet..."

Comment: Note: The sheets ("summary1", "extract1") mentioned might not be the first sheet in the workbook. Their position might change

Comment: For the error - make sure in your options (VBA editor >> Tools >> Options >> General) you don't have "Break on all errors" checked.  "Break in class module" is a good option.  The order of sheets in the workbook doesn't matter - it only searches by name.

Comment: Just tested this, and it's working fine for me.  Make sure you copy the entire code as-is.

Comment: You meant `If Not ws Is Nothing Then Set FindFirstSheet = ws: Exit Function` or `Exit For` without the outer `Set FindFirstSheet = ws`.

Comment: @VBasic2008 - it works as-is in my testing.  Maybe just a different pattern than you might use?  Once the loop exits, ws is either a worksheet or Nothing.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It just looks more correct to me since `ws` is initially `Nothing`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me. As usual thank you for your valuable inputs!! much appriciated

Sub PIdataextraction()

```
    Dim myFile As String, path As String
    Dim erow As Long, col As Long
   
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim copyrange As Range, cel As Range
   
    path = "C:\Users\New\"
    myFile = Dir(path & "*.xl??")
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    Do While myFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (path & myFile)
        Windows(myFile).Activate
       
        On Error Resume Next
        Set shtSrc = Worksheets("summary1")
        If Err = 9 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set shtSrc = Worksheets("extract1")
            If Err = 9 Then Exit Sub
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
             
        Set copyrange = shtSrc.Range("B4,E7,E9,E11,E13,E15,I12,J22,C24,C25,C26,I11,R16")
       
        Windows("MasterFile.xlsm").Activate
       
        erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       
        col = 1
        For Each cel In copyrange
            Cells(erow, col).Value = cel.Value   ' Equivalent of xlPasteValues
            col = col + 1     
        Next
       
        Windows(myFile).Close savechanges:=False
        myFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Range("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
   
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
    MsgBox "Data has been Compiled,Please Check!"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way i can add excel file names at the end of each row i pull(results) i.e. for each workbook macro opens? This would help!! Thanks

Comment: See edit in my answer