# The file name of the excel workbooks the Macro pulls data from to be recorded

Tags: excel, vba

I would want the file names to be recorded in the "MasterFile" next to the data pulled from the respective files, so that i can map data items to the file names.

Any guidance/ ideas are much appreciated!! Thanks in advance :)

Code:

```
Sub PIDataExtraction()

    Dim myFile As String, Path As String
    Dim erow As Long, col As Long
   
    Dim shtSrc As Worksheet
    Dim copyrange As Range, cel As Range
   
    fpath = Range("B2").Value
    myFile = Dir(Path & "*.xl??")
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   
    Do While myFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open (Path & myFile)
        Windows(myFile).Activate
       
        On Error Resume Next
        Set shtSrc = Worksheets("RX Ratings Price Calculator")
        If err = 9 Then
            On Error Resume Next
            Set shtSrc = Worksheets("Feed Content Pricing Guideline")
            If err = 9 Then Exit Sub
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
             
        Set copyrange = shtSrc.Range("B4,E7,E9,E11,E13,E15,Ratings_Universe_Default,J22,C24,C25,C26,I11,R16")
       
        Windows("MasterFile.xlsm").Activate
       
        erow = Data.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
       
        col = 1
        For Each cel In copyrange
            Cells(erow, col).Value = cel.Value
            col = col + 1
        Next
       
        Windows(myFile).Close savechanges:=False
        myFile = Dir()
    Loop
    Range("A:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
   
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
   
    MsgBox "Data has been Compiled,Please Check!"

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to write `myFile` then next to the cells in question?

Comment: Answered on your previous post.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70980214/478884