# Why does "bCheck" always return "True"?

Tags: excel, vba, function, boolean

I have been working on a `Macro` that will automatically add new `Annual Worksheets` when the `Calendar Year` Changes. My current `Code` is as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub addAnnualWkst()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsM As Worksheet
Dim strName As String
Dim strNamePreYr As String
Dim bCheck As Boolean
Dim pID As String
Dim rw

Set propIDs = ThisWorkbook.Names("propIDs").RefersToRange
Set actStatus = ThisWorkbook.Names("actStatus").RefersToRange

On Error Resume Next
Set wsM = Worksheets("WkstMaster")
    For rw = 1 To propIDs.Count
        If propIDs.Cells(rw, 1).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            If actStatus.Cells(rw, 1).Value2 = True Then
              pID = propIDs.Cells(rw, 1).Value2
              strName = pID & "_" & (Format(Date, "yyyy"))
              strNamePreYr = pID & "_" & (Format(Date, "yyyy") - 1)
              bCheck = Len(Sheets(strName).Name) > 0
              Debug.Print pID, strName, strNamePreYr, bCheck
                If bCheck = False Then
                'add new sheet after Previous Year's Worksheet
                    wsM.Copy After:=Sheets(strNamePreYr)
                    ActiveSheet.Name = strName
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Set wsM = Nothing
End Sub
```

the code above is based in part on on a `Macro` I found in a `Tutorial` I found [image: here] and the `Module Code` is:

```
Option Explicit

Sub AddMonthWkst()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsM As Worksheet
Dim strName As String
Dim bCheck As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Set wsM = Sheets("Wkst_Master")
strName = Format(Date, "yyyy_mm")
bCheck = Len(Sheets(strName).Name) > 0

If bCheck = False Then
'add new sheet after Instructions
    wsM.Copy After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = strName
End If

Set wsM = Nothing
End Sub
```

The above 'code' works as advertised! `bCheck` returns `False` and the new worksheet is added. I am able to rename the worksheet tab from the current month  `05` to the previous month `04`, save and close the workbook and when I reopen the workbook a new worksheet is automatically added with the `05` month extension.

I modified the code slightly to fit my needs and incapsulated that code in a `subroutine` I successfully use in different parts of the application where I select `pIDs` based on `actStatus`.

I have active `Worksheet Tabs` for the various `PropIDs` as shown in this image:

[image: Worksheet_Tab]

When I run the `Macro` the `Immediate Window` shows **ALL** `Active pIDs` with a `pCheck Value` as `True` when the `pID "Rev"` should return a value of `False` because `pID "Rev"` does not have a `WorkSheet` for the current year!
As one can see for the `Immediate window` screenshot below, all the relevant `pIDs` are there!
[image: Immediate Window]

If I disable the 'On Error Resume Next' line I get the `Runtime Error: 9, Script out of range` error and with or without the `Error Trap` the worksheet is not added. the `Error` happens at the `highlighted` line of `code`.
[image]

Please help me to resolve this issue. I know it is something simple I am missing!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to check if a sheet exists. If so, use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists).

Comment: It returns true, as it's just chekcing the length of the proposed name for the new sheet.  This will always be >0 due to adding `& "_" & (Format(Date, "yyyy"))` so if PID was empty, then it still would be true.  As @bigben says, you're looking for the worksheet exists code.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav, the first line of code after the `For` statement ensures the `pID` cannot be `EMPTY`, and the secone `If` statements ensures that only `pIDs` with an `actStatus = True`  are included in the list of worksheets to test. this is confirmed in the `Immediate Window` image  I included! The `Screenshot` showing the worksheet tabs shows that `Rev_2022` does not exist! Why does `bCheck` return `True`?

Comment: @BigBen, I took a look at the link in your comment and after sorting things out a bit, I came up with a solution based on the second `Answer` in that thread. You may see what I did in My answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is your problem:

```vb
Sub TesterLoop()
    Dim bCheck As Boolean, s
    
    On Error Resume Next
    'Sheet4 doesn't exist
    For Each s In Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet4")
        'if the next line has an error then the value of bCheck is *unchanged*
        bCheck = Len(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(s).Name) > 0
        Debug.Print s, bCheck
    Next s
End Sub
```

Output:

```txt
Sheet1        True
Sheet2        True
Sheet4        True   '<<<oops!  Still has the Sheet2 value...
```

The value of `bCheck` can only be set when that line executes with no error: if there's an error then `bCheck` still has its initial `False` value, or the value from the previous loop iteration.

If you add

`bCheck = False`

before that line it will fix your problem.

**But** it's a bad idea to let `On Error Resume Next` cover that much of your code, and you'd be better off factoring out that check into a standalone function as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Tim, thanks for the pointers. I finally figured out who to use a `Function' with the original `Sub`. Everything works **WITHOUT** the need for `Error Handlers`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who pointed me in direction of a possible solution.

Here is the the Solution I came up with!

```
Sub addAnnualWkst()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsM As Worksheet
Dim strName As String
Dim strNamePreYr As String
Dim bCheck As Boolean
Dim exists
Dim pID As String
Dim rw

Set propIDs = ThisWorkbook.Names("propIDs").RefersToRange
Set actStatus = ThisWorkbook.Names("actStatus").RefersToRange

Set wsM = Worksheets("WkstMaster")
    For rw = 1 To propIDs.Count
        If propIDs.Cells(rw, 1).Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            If actStatus.Cells(rw, 1).Value2 = True Then
              pID = propIDs.Cells(rw, 1).Value2
              cName = pID & (Format(Date, "yyyy"))
              strName = pID & "_" & (Format(Date, "yyyy"))
              strNamePreYr = pID & "_" & (Format(Date, "yyyy") - 1)
                If Not wsExists(strName) Then
                Debug.Print pID, strName, strNamePreYr
                  wsM.Copy After:=Sheets(strNamePreYr)
                  ActiveSheet.Name = strName
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
Set wsM = Nothing
End Sub
```

```
Function wsExists(strName As String) As Boolean
    Dim ws: For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    wsExists = (strName = ws.Name): If wsExists Then Exit Function
    Next ws
End Function
```

The only 'pID' that appears in the `Immediate Window` is the `pID` missing the `2022` extension.

Comment: `For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets` or you run the risk of a bug if your workbook is not the active workbook when this runs.

Comment: @Tim, thanks, I'll adjust the code.