# If Sheet Name Doesn't Exist, How to Skip to the Next Loop?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, arraylist, skip

i is an arraylist of names. j is using that list as tab names. The problem Im running into is that  if that range of cells has an empty cell in it -- or if the name in the array list doesn't exist how would I "skip that name" (or empty cell) and go to the next loop? I think it would be under j, but I'm not sure where to begin other than an if statement? not sure how to write an if statement for that either?

```
Set Tail = New ArrayList

Dim NewestEntry As Integer
Dim Apple As String
        
For i = 0 To 20 Step 3 'Tail #/Number of Tails

    Apple = Worksheets("StepBrief").Cells(i + 6, 3).Value
    Tail.Add Apple
                        
Next i

For j = 0 To 20 'Number of Tail # Cells
        
            NewestEntry = Worksheets(Tail(j)).Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists/6688482#6688482

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Skip Blanks and Existing Values in `ArrayList`

- Learn about the ArrayList on [this *Excel MacroMastery's* webpage](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-arraylist/).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestArrayList()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("StepBrief")
   
    Dim Tail As ArrayList: Set Tail = New ArrayList ' (early binding)
    ' If you don't want to create a reference to 'mscorlib.dll' since
    ' at this moment the array list's intelli-sense doesn't work anyway,
    ' instead, you could use (late binding):
    'Dim Tail As Object: Set Tail = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    
    Dim Apple As String
    Dim i As Long
                    
    For i = 6 To 26 Step 3
        Apple = CStr(ws.Cells(i, "C").Value)
        If Len(Apple) > 0 Then ' is not blank
            If Not Tail.Contains(Apple) Then ' is not already in array list
                Tail.Add Apple
            'Else ' already in array list; do nothing
            End If
        'Else ' is blank; do nothing
        End If
    Next i

    ' Some examples of what to do with it:

    ' Print the contents of 'Tail'.
    
    Dim Item As Variant
    
    For Each Item In Tail
        Debug.Print Item
    Next Item
    
    ' Write the values from 'Tail' to an array.
    Dim Arr As Variant: Arr = Tail.ToArray
    
    ' Print the contents of the array.
    For i = 0 To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print i, Arr(i)
    Next i

    ' Print the contents of the array as a comma-separated list using 'Join'
    ' (since the elements are strings).
    Debug.Print Join(Arr, ",")
    
End Sub
```