# Worksheet exists, not go to next workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How do I check whether a certain worksheet exists in the workbook? If not, go to next workbook. If yes, perform certain actions on it.
I am looping through multiple workbooks.

```
Function WorksheetExists(app173 As String, Activeworkbook wb As Workbook) As Boolean
         Dim app173 As Worksheet

         Not sure what steps to include here in my case
End Function
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Test or check if sheet exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)

Answer (score 0):

### Find Worksheet in Multiple Open Workbooks

```vb
Sub FindWorksheet()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    
    ' Caution! This also references hidden workbooks (e.g. PERSONAL.xlsb).
    For Each wb In Workbooks
        On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not ws Is Nothing Then ' found
            ' Perform actions, e.g.:
            Debug.Print wb.Name, ws.Name
            
            Set ws = Nothing ' reset for the next iteration
        'Else ' not found; do nothing
        End If
    Next wb
     
End Sub
```