# How to check whether certain sheets exist or not in Excel-VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

Does anyone know how to check whether certain sheets exist or not in an Excel document using Excel VBA?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although (unfortunately) such method is not available, we can create our own function to check this..

Hope the code below fits your needs.

**Edit1:** Added also delete statement...

```
Sub test()

    If CheckSheet(Sheets(3).Name) then

        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets(Sheets(3).Name).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End If

End Sub
```

The solution I'd go for...

```
Function CheckSheet(ByVal sSheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        If oSheet.Name = sSheetName Then

            bReturn = True
            Exit For

        End If

    Next oSheet

    CheckSheet = bReturn

End Function
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind to use code that actively raise errors (which is not recommended by common coding best practices) you could use this '[Spartan Programming](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/spartan-programming.html) wannabe' code below...

```
Function CheckSheet(ByVal sSheetName As String) As Boolean

    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim bReturn As Boolean

    For Each oSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        If oSheet.Name = sSheetName Then

            bReturn = True
            Exit For

        End If

    Next oSheet

    CheckSheet = bReturn

End Function


Function CheckSheet(ByVal sSheetName As String) As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Set oSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sSheetName)
    CheckSheet = IIf(oSheet Is Nothing, False, True)

End Function
```

Comment: This is also an excellent solution -- checks without relying on errors. I knew there was a better way, and I had used this way before at work, I just couldn't remember how to do it.  

@Tiago: How would you use it on Sheets(1)?  Just pass in Sheets(1).Name?

Comment: @PaulR, yeap, exactly... `Sheets(1).name` would do the trick. Notice you may need to actively define the workbooks you're going to use, since a 'sheet' reference implicitly points to the active workbook (which is not the expected, sometimes).

Comment: Right, I've had that bite me at work sometimes. For larger operations, I tend to use a With block for my Worksheets("SheetName") object, and call it good.   This would be, of course, after I made sure Worksheets("SheetName") existed.

Comment: Hi @Tiago Cardoso thanks for answering. But sorry if i've asking amateur questions here. I'm rather new to excel-vba, but with my context I've checking if these sheets(2) and (3) exist i've wanted to initial a delete function but now with your above codes. How should implement it this function?

Comment: Hi @PaulR i have updated my code above as i have encounter some problem while implementing Tiago Cardoso code. Can you take a look and give me some suggestions here as to how to solve it. Thanks

Comment: @Tiago Cardoso I have updated my codes above can you take a look and give me some suggestion as to how can i solve it?

Comment: @Vivian added now the deletion code, hope it's better now. Going to bed, I'll see if everything is fine tomorrow. ;)

Comment: @Vivian, your deletion code based on Tiago's looks sound.

Comment: Actually in VBA it is best practice (and many times the only way) to determine a lot of things by catching errors.

Comment: Agree, @Lance. My point is that in this specific case of 'Resume Next', we are actively *creating* an error instead of *checking* if an error would be raised. A simple way to make it break would be to change VBA's Error Trapping from *Break on Unhandled Errors* to *Break on All Errors*. Ideally, IMO, our applications would run smoothly with the Error Trapping set to *Break on All Errors*, but that's not the case for most of VBA developers.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will get you started:

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim wSheet as Worksheet
Set wSheet = Sheets(1) ' can also be a string, such as Sheets("Sheet1")

If wSheet Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Worksheet not found!"
    Set wSheet = Nothing ' make the worksheet point to nothing. 
    On Error GoTo 0 
Else 
    MsgBox "Worksheet found!"
    Set wSheet = Nothing ' set the found Worksheet object to nothing.  You can use the found wSheet for your purposes, though.  
End If
```

This code was based on http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/IsWorkbookOpen.htm.  Look for the DoesSheetExist() sub.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I adapted this code for use in LotusScript, one of the languages used by IBM Notes (formerly Lotus Notes) as shown below.

```
Public Function ExcelSheetExists( _
    xlBook As Variant, _ ' Excel workbook object
    ByVal strSheetName As String _
    ) As Boolean

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    ForAll xlSheet In xlBook.Sheets
        If xlSheet.Name = strSheetName Then
            ExcelSheetExists = True
            Exit Forall
        End If
    End ForAll

    GoTo Done

errHandler:
    ' Call MyCustomErrorHandler()
    Resume Done
Done:

End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
On Error GoTo Line1
If Sheets("BOX2").Index > 0 Then
Else
Line1: MsgBox ("BOX2 is missing")
end if
```

I did it this way:)