# Generate sheets corresponding to row values (duplicate values exist)

Tags: excel, error-handling, dynamically-generated, worksheet, vba

I have a main worksheet (Install_Input) where sheet number, test section, and material are manually entered by user.

(Below: illustration of Install_Input ws: Range A1:C8)

Sheet# | TestSection | Material

.....1.....|..........A..........|.STEEL.|

.....2.....|..........B..........|.PLASTIC.|

.....3.....|..........C..........|.STEEL.|

.....5.....|..........G..........|.STEEL.|

.....2.....|..........F..........|.PLASTIC.|

.....2.....|..........A..........|.STEEL.|

.....5.....|..........D..........|.PLASTIC.|

I want to generate sheets within the current workbook that correspond to sheet numbers entered in Install_Input.  The code I made will generate a new sheet for each value in MyRange, however, **I would like for my code to skip over generating sheets that already exist**.  I tried using the "On Error Resume Next" and "On Error GoTo 0" commands to solve this problem, but they just generated unnamed sheets to compensate for those that already exist.

```
Sub Consolidate_Sheets()
    Dim MyCell As Range
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Install_Input").Range("A2")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))


    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        If Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name <> MyCell.Value Then
            'On Error Resume Next
            Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 
            Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value 
            'On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following two functions:

```
    Function getSheetWithDefault(name As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook) As Excel.Worksheet
        If wb Is Nothing Then
            Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        End If

        If Not sheetExists(name, wb) Then
            wb.Worksheets.Add(After:=wb.Worksheets(wb.Worksheets.Count)).name = name
        End If

        Set getSheetWithDefault = wb.Sheets(name)
    End Function

    Function sheetExists(name As String, Optional wb As Excel.Workbook) As Boolean
        Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

        If wb Is Nothing Then
            Set wb = ThisWorkbook
        End If

        sheetExists = False
        For Each sheet In wb.Worksheets
            If sheet.name = name Then
                sheetExists = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next sheet
    End Function
```

To use it in your code:

```
    Sub Consolidate_Sheets()
        Dim MyCell As Range
        Dim MyRange As Range
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        Set MyRange = Sheets("Install_Input").Range("A2")
        Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

        For Each MyCell In MyRange
            If Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name <> MyCell.Value Then
                'On Error Resume Next
                set ws = getSheetWithDefault(MyCell.Value)
                'On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next MyCell
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a `CheckSheet` function like the one described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838826/179) that loops through all existing sheets and compares the name of each sheet with the passed-in value.