# Do we have 'Exists' function to search for the excel sheets using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

My excel workbook sheets are named with the dates("DD-MMM-YYYY") and I have to get the data from each sheet in to another excel. When i use for loop(from date to date), the date for which the sheet is not available is holding back my script.Do we have something called not exists in VBA?

```
Sub gettheTips()
 Dim fromDate As Date
 Dim toDate As Date

 fromDate = InputBox("Enter the From date for the tips")
 toDate = InputBox("Enter the To date for the tips")

    'Ensure that from date less than the to date
    If (fromDate < toDate) Then

       'Select all the tips from date todate
        For i = fromDate To toDate
         dt = Format(i, "d-mmm-yyyy")
         'MsgBox (dt)
            'copy paste the tips from all the days to the Report sheet
            If Worksheet(dt <> "") Then

               Sheets(dt).Select
                Range("E9").Select
                Selection.Copy
                Sheets("Report").Select
                Range("E17").Select
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            Else
             MsgBox ("The worksheet named" & dt & "does not exists")
            End If

          Next
    Else
    MsgBox ("From Date is greater than the todate entered")

End Sub
```

I expect the code to display messagebox worksheet named "" doesnot exists when the dated sheet is not available in workbook

Comment: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838437/how-to-check-whether-certain-sheets-exist-or-not-in-excel-vba) Hope the answer on this link helps

Comment: @saad , Thank You. It helped me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether certain sheets exist or not in Excel-VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838437/how-to-check-whether-certain-sheets-exist-or-not-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Test or check if sheet exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)