# How to check if the Worksheet exists in the Excel file

Tags: excel, matlab

I have an Excel file which contains more than 20 sheet. I am writing a module in Matlab where I need to check if a particular worksheet say for example 'SalaryData' is present in the Excel file.

I am not able to use `xlsinfo` I think, this function is not available in the Matlab version I am currently using.

I intend to use actxserver to check the existence of the worksheet. What I am currently doing is something like :

```
SheetExist=1;
try
  sheet = get(Excel.Worksheets,'Item',sheetname);
catch
  disp('File Does not exist');
  SheetExist=0;
end
```

I think there is a much better and a easier way to check.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/excel-vba-if-worksheetwsname-exists

Comment: I don't know matlab, but that looks about right to me.

Comment: @Steve Robillard: no, no duplicate, this question is for matlab, not VBA

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [xlsfinfo](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/xlsfinfo.html) function:

```
[~, sheets] = xlsfinfo(filename);
ismember(sheetname,sheets);
```

Notice that the sheetname is case sensitive by using the ismember function! If you want case insensitivity, use a loop and [strcmpi](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/strcmpi.html).

EDIT: just noticed your remark about xlsinfo :p
Are you sure it is not available? You mention xlsinfo is not available, but the actual function is called xlsfinfo! notice the 'f' between 'xls' and 'info'

Comment: Wonderful, I just missed an 'f' in ´xlsfinfo´. I just dropped an f word.. quiet literally.. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Will this help?

```
SheetExist=1;    
Set ws = Sheets(“sheet_name”)
If ws Is Nothing Then SheetExist=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. Is it VBA code ? What I am trying is very similar. I am looking at a function similar to `exist()` in matlab.