# Run Macros if Sheet Does Not Exist

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to only run a set of macros if a sheet doesn't already exist. I have a macro that creates a sheet and combines data from two sheets into it, and another that formats the new sheet. Since it needs to run on workbook open, I can't have it recreating the sheet again and again. I have been trying the following, but it gives the error: "sub or Function not defined":

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If SheetExist("MyNewSheet") Then
End Sub
Else
Combine
Format
End Sub
```

Comment: Yea, the problem is "End Sub" should be "Exit Sub" You can also use the solution below. If SheetExist("MyNewSheet") Then Exit Sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't doing anything if the sheet exists, so change your test.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If Not SheetExist("MyNewSheet") Then
        Combine
        Format
    End If
End Sub

Function SheetExist(sheetname As String) As Boolean
    SheetExist = True ' replace this with code from link below
End Function
```

Use the answers here: [Excel VBA If WorkSheet("wsName") Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6040164/138938) for examples of functions that determine whether the sheet exists.

Comment: This is working: Private Sub Workbook_Open()
If Not e("MyNewSheet") Then
        Combine
        Format
    End If
End Sub

Function e(n As String) As Boolean
  e = False
  For Each ws In Worksheets
    If n = ws.Name Then
      e = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next ws
End Function

Answer (score 2):

Yea, the problem is "End Sub" should be "Exit Sub" You can also use the solution above/below.

Your fixed code would be:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If SheetExists("MyNewSheet") Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Combine
    Format
End If

End Sub
```

Also:

```
Public Function SheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean 

On Error Resume Next
WorksheetExists = (Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: It is still giving me a compile error: Sub or Function not defined. Current code is: Private Sub Workbook_Open()

If SheetExist("MyNewSheet") Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    Combine
    Format
End If

End Sub

Public Function SheetExists(ByVal WorksheetName As String) As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
WorksheetExists = (Sheets(WorksheetName).Name <> "")
On Error GoTo 0

End Function

Comment: Should be If SheetExists my bad