# Export Power Queries from One Workbook to Another with VBA

Tags: vba, excel, powerquery

I am looking to transfer power queries from one workbook to another with VBA. I know how to do this manually but it is very cumbersome.

A power query can be accessed via the Workbook.Connections object. 
I am currently attempting to port the queries over with a VBA function or Sub.

The manual process is as follows

- for each query in workbook 1
- open up workbook 1 and go to advanced editor - copy into a text editor
- open up workbook 2 create query, and paste text into advanced editor
- ensure source tables are the same - and run query to validate

Comment: See here for how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Please start coding and come back when you have a specific question if/when you get stuck as this is not a code factory.  Perhaps this: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2015/06/10/power-queryexcel-2016-vba-examples/ can help you get started.  Welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I will update it. I referenced other questions, and the question is valid. I mentioned the Workbook.Connections object which is techincially code.

Comment: An object is not code.  If you did not know how to use the object or were asking something specific about an object, then this would be an on topic question.  As is, you basically said, "I want to do something.  I have no idea how to do it, but maybe this object is relevant.  I have not tried anything, and I have not created any code.  Please code the entire solution for me."  The other questions probably were not good either.  Once you actually tried to do it yourself, you actually did, in less than 2 hours.  I'm glad that you took the initiative.

Comment: I agree. Im a stack noob. My bad

Comment: An alternative manual process is: open the Workbook Queries pane for the source file, select all the queries, right-click and choose copy, open the Workbook Queries pane for the target file, right-click and choose paste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve it by using the Workbook.Query object.

here is my solution.

```
            Public Sub FunctionToTest_ForStackOverflow()
                ' Doug.Long
                Dim wb As Workbook

                ' create empty workbook
                Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
                Set wb = NewBook

                ' copy queries
                CopyPowerQueries ThisWorkbook, wb, True

            End Sub

            Public Sub CopyPowerQueries(wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, Optional ByVal copySourceData As Boolean)
                ' Doug.Long
                ' copy power queries into new workbook
                Dim qry As WorkbookQuery
                For Each qry In wb1.Queries
                    ' copy source data
                    If copySourceData Then
                        CopySourceDataFromPowerQuery wb1, wb2, qry
                    End If

                    ' add query to workbook
                    wb2.Queries.Add qry.Name, qry.formula, qry.Description
                Next
            End Sub

            Public Sub CopySourceDataFromPowerQuery(wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook, qry As WorkbookQuery)
                ' Doug.Long
                ' copy source data by pulling data out from workbook into other
                Dim qryStr As String
                Dim sourceStrCount As Integer
                Dim i As Integer
                Dim tbl As ListObject
                Dim sht As Worksheet

                sourceStrCount = (Len(qry.formula) - Len(Replace$(qry.formula, "Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook()", ""))) / Len("Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook()")

                For i = 1 To sourceStrCount
                    qryStr = Split(Split(qry.formula, "Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=""")(1), """]}")(0)
                    For Each sht In wb1.Worksheets
                        For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
                            If tbl.Name = qryStr Then
                                If Not sheetExists(sht.Name) Then
                                    sht.Copy After:=wb2.Sheets(wb2.Sheets.Count)
                                End If
                            End If
                        Next tbl
                    Next sht
                Next i

                qryStr = qry.formula


            End Sub


            Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
                'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/excel-vba-if-worksheetwsname-exists
                sheetExists = False
                For Each sheet In Worksheets
                    If sheetToFind = sheet.Name Then
                        sheetExists = True
                        Exit Function
                    End If
                Next sheet
            End Function
```