# Excel VBA Check if worksheet exists before copy worksheet to workbook a

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying develop a macro that pulls in all sheets from all workbooks in a folder if that worksheet doesn't already exist in the master workbook. 
IE

```
Folder  
|---Summary Sheet.xlsm  
|---Sheet 1 date1.xlsx  
|---Sheet 2 date2.xlsx   
etc.
```

The macro opens the workbook, renames the sheet to the date off a cell, copies it across then closes it without saving/prompting. I can't seem to incorporate the name check correctly. I've looked over
[Test or check if sheet exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6688131/test-or-check-if-sheet-exists)
[Excel VBA If WorkSheet("wsName") Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/excel-vba-if-worksheetwsname-exists)
But lack the experience to properly translate the concepts across.

This is the code so far. Running now throws a runtime error 438 with
sheetToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

```
Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Dim sheetToFind As String
Dim sheetExists As Boolean

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

FolderPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Folder\"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")

 Do While Filename <> ""
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
 sheetExists = False

 For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
   Sheet.Name = Sheet.Range("C4")
   sheetToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
     sheetExists = True
   End If

   If sheetExists = False Then
     Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
     Workbooks(Filename).Close False
     Filename = Dir()
   End If
  Next Sheet
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` is an object and needs `Set`. => `Set sheetToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)`... but also `sheetToFind = Sheet.Name` would fail as `sheetToFind` is an object which cannot be compared like that... `sheetToFind.Name = Sheet.Name` should do the trick there ;)

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand. If I go `Do.. sheetToFind.Name = Sheet.Name   For Each Sheet....` I get an invalid qualifier error. Have I left something out or put it in the wrong place?     Can I search all sheet names to compare the renamed sheet to?

Comment: Simply try to change `sheetToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)` to `sheetToFind = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Name` and check if it is doing what you want

Answer (score 0):

The problem I faced with the answers above were that they didn't check each sheet each time. I found another function from
[Excel VBA If WorkSheet("wsName") Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/excel-vba-if-worksheetwsname-exists#6040454)

Using that I was able to make everything work.

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next Sheet
End Function

Sub ConslidateWorkbooks()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Filename As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
FolderPath = Environ("userprofile") & "\Folder\"
Filename = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")

Do While Filename <> ""
  Workbooks.Open Filename:=FolderPath & Filename, ReadOnly:=True
  For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Name = Sheet.Range("C4")
    result = sheetExists(Sheet.Name)
    Debug.Print result
    If result = True Then
      Workbooks(Filename).Close False
      Filename = Dir()
    End If
    If result = False Then
      Sheet.Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
      Workbooks(Filename).Close False
      Filename = Dir()
    End If
  Next Sheet
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```