# VBA filtering list using data extracted from filtered list

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have an Excel file that I filtered based on criteria in three columns, meaning that from 13k rows in went down to 100 (99 + header), this part works fine.

What I need to do next and can't get to work is extract a list of values from column F (these values are strings containing letters, numbers and hyphens - no idea if this matters), remove all the filtering and filter the same file again (by column F) based on the list extracted from column F (which will then show me the 99 original lines + additional lines containing additional information for all of them).
Below is the part of the code that I can't get to work.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
Dim LR As Long, ws As Worksheet, Criteria As Variant
       
Set ws = ActiveSheet
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  
Criteria = ws.Range("F2:F" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
    
Cells.AutoFilter
    
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BY" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Application.Transpose(Criteria), _ 
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

My filtering only includes the very first value from the list of values I want to extract from column F.

`MsgBox (Criteria)` seems to confirm that it only picked up the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before filtering your data, make sure it's not already filtered. If it's already filtered, your code will add an additional filter without replacing the existing filter.
Add this before your first filter to remove any existing filters:
`If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False`

Try copying the filtered data to a separate sheet, it may be easier to manage that way.

```
'Create a temp sheet    
If Not SheetExists("TempSheet") Then ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add _
    (After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "TempSheet"
Dim TempSheet As Worksheet
Set TempSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TempSheet")

'Copy your values to the temp sheet
Dim lastRow As Long
With ws
    lastRow = (.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
    .Range("F2" & ":F" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy _
    TempSheet.Range("A1")
End With

'Now you create a string array with the results:
Dim lastTempRow As Long
lastTempRow = (TempSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
Dim paramsArr() As String
ReDim paramsArr(lastTempRow - 1) As String
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To lastTempRow - 1
    paramsArr(i) = TempSheet.Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value
Next i

'use the array as your criteria
ws.Range("A1:BY" & lastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=paramsArr, _
    Operator:=xlFilterValues

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If SheetExists("TempSheet") Then TempSheet.Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

*SheetExists is a function written about [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/if-worksheetwsname-exists#:%7E:text=A%20version%20without%20error%2Dhandling%3A):*

*ETA:
I posted my answer before I realized that you answered. Our answers are similar, but I'll list the differences in my answer.* 
Some changes:

- Gave more descriptive variable names
- Got rid of the `Select`s and `Activate`s for efficiency.
- Used the `Destination:=` argument in the `.Copy` method. This bypasses the clipboard and is more efficient.
- Named the worksheet that was added. This enabled me to easily delete it at the end of the code, when it is no longer needed.
- Gave a specific type to `Criteria` instead of `Variant`. It's more descriptive and efficient this way.

Comment: @MrPulles
I don't have enough reputation to comment on your answer, hopefully you see this.
Your code is working on my machine. The only thing I added was `If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False`.
If the sheet is filtered it would not behave as expected.

You can also see the value of Criteria in the VBA code editor.
Set a breakpoint on the line after `Criteria = ws.Range("F2:F" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value`, then open the locals window (View > Locals Window). Click on the little + next to Criteria and expand each + to see the value.

Comment: when you say that my code is working on your machine you mean my original code and not my workaround, right? The sheet is not filtered when my macro opens the file, it just applies the necessary filters so that only the relevant information can be copied from column F.
Or do you mean later when I remove the filters to filter again, i.e. should I replace `Cells.AutoFilter` by `If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False`? I'm not sure where this line should be exactly.
As for your second solution it is the same as mine but coded differently, right?

Comment: "when you say that my code is working on your machine you mean my original code and not my workaround, right?"
Yes, the only thing I changed is I added `If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False` after `Set ws = ActiveSheet`. This is effectively the same as `Cells.AutoFilter`.

Comment: "The sheet is not filtered when my macro opens the file, it just applies the necessary filters so that only the relevant information can be copied from column F. Or do you mean later when I remove the filters to filter again, i.e. should I replace Cells.AutoFilter by If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False?"
See above. No need to replace `Cells.AutoFilter`.

"As for your second solution it is the same as mine but coded differently, right?"
Correct. I didn't realize that you answered your question until after I posted my answer. Great minds think alike...
:)

Answer (score 0):

So I found a workaround, I just copied the list of values from column F to a newly created second sheet (my file originally has just one sheet) and then defined my variant called criteria from there.

```
Range("F2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
    
Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(1)
    
Worksheets(2).Activate
    
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
   
Dim LR As Long, ws As Worksheet, Criteria As Variant
Set ws = ActiveSheet
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
Criteria = Worksheets(2).Range("A1:A" & LR)
    
Worksheets(1).Activate
    
Cells.AutoFilter
    
LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:BY" & LR).AutoFilter Field:=6, _ 
criteria1:=Application.Transpose(Criteria), Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

However I would still be interested in what I did wrong in my original code if anyone has an idea.